# Inheriting from a Managed Class

Tags: inheritance, c++-cli, unmanaged, managed

Is there a way to inherit & extend a Managed class (written in C#) by an C++/CLI class?

Comment: Yes, the assembly format is language agnostic.  Simply add a reference to the C# assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but there may be some gotchas (e.g. disposable classes).

See here for example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/CppDerivingDispose.aspx